# Enter bean value into hidden input in Struts (1.x) with different name than bean

Tags: html, jsp, struts, jsp-tags, javabeans

So I have a generic form bean I am using that has a few values such as action, offer, code.

I am developing a new form that uses this generic form (required) but I want to use the value of a bean that has a name different from the bean I get values from to populate the form page.

On the first load of the page it displays some basic data:

```
Action: (hidden input, name the same as the bean)
<html:hidden property="action"/>

Offer: (user input, name the same as the bean)
<html:text property="offer"/>

Code: (hidden input, name not the same as the bean)
<html:hidden property="code"/>
```

The bean I was to use is something like:

```
<bean:write name="data" property="data.code.description"/>
```

How do I get that value (data.code.desription) into the "hidden" code area so that when the form is submitted the generic form bean picks up the value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="code" value="<bean:write name="data" property="data.code.description"/>" />
```

Answer (score 6):

Why not just this?

```
<html:hidden property="data.code.description" name="scoreform_bean"/>
```

Refer to the [javadocs for more](https://struts.apache.org/docs/hidden.html) and [Struts html:hidden Tag](http://kruders.com/struts/struts-html-hidden-tag/)